# Save image from an image box to gallery in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to save the picture in an image control to the Android gallery in Xamarin Forms? All help is appreciated.

```
var image = new Image();
image.Source = "test.png";
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M1eu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Dependency Service` to get the stream from `Resource/drawable` image.

Create the IDependency interface.

```
public interface IDependency
{
    MemoryStream DrawableByNameToByteArray(string fileName);
}
```

Android implementation

```
public class DependencyImplementation : IDependency
{
    public MemoryStream DrawableByNameToByteArray(string fileName)
    {
        var context = Application.Context;
        using (var drawable = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ResourceManager.GetDrawable(context, fileName))
        using (var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            bitmap.Recycle();
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

For the IOS implementation, you could refer to the thread in SO.
[Convert Image (from drawable folder) to ByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484309/convert-image-from-drawable-folder-to-bytearray)

And then register in Android Mainactivity.

```
DependencyService.Register<IDependency, DependencyImplementation>();
```

If your android version is highter than android 6.0, you need runtime permission for storage in this question. Please check the `Plugin.Permissions` with runtime permission.
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

After that, you could save the image to picture internal storage.

```
var filename = "";
        var source = image.Source as FileImageSource;
        if (source != null)
        {
            filename = source.File;
        }

        var savingFile = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        //var savingFile1 = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "save.png");
        var S = DependencyService.Get<IDependency>().DrawableByNameToByteArray(filename);


        if (!File.Exists(savingFile))
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(savingFile, S.ToArray());               
        }
```

In Internal Storage, you couldn't see the files without root permission. 
If you want to view it, you could use adb tool. 
Please check the way in link.
[How to write the username in a local txt file when login success and check on file for next login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966590/how-to-write-the-username-in-a-local-txt-file-when-login-success-and-check-on-fi/56981010#56981010)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media Plugin and it can solve your issue. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

You can visit the above link.

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        Directory = "Sample",
        Name = "test.jpg"
    });

    if (file == null)
        return;

    await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        return stream;
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Ok, can you provide some example code? Sorry, I'm still fairly new to Xamarin Forms. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I'm not trying to take a photo. I'm trying to save a photo in a picture box to the gallery.